# The meaning of "span" that belongs to horses

Tags: meaning, poetry

In the poem "One and one" of Mary Mapes Dodge there is a line:

> Two little ponies must go to a span

It seems, the "span" here is some term belonging to horses. Obviously, some place where they run or stay. But which one? I can't find it in dictionaries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is an old usage that refers to a pair of horses driven together:

***[Span:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/span)***

> - (obsolete) A pair of horses or other animals driven together; usually, such a pair of horses when similar in color, form, and action.

Wiktionary

[Origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=span):

> - "two animals driven together," 1769, American English, from Dutch span, from spannen "to stretch or yoke," from Middle Dutch spannan. Also used in South African English.

Etymonline

[image]
from: (www.youtube.com)

Comment: As a sidenote, while `span` exists in Dutch with the exact same meaning, I'm more used to hearing `tweespan` (described [here](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mennen_(paardensport))); `twee` is Dutch for `two`. I suppose `tweespan` is the colloquial term for this configuration (for horses, at least). Dutch also has the terms `enkelspan` (single span), meaning that a single horse is used, and [vierspan](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vierspan) (`vier` means `four`), which has two pairs of two horses (one in front of the other).This can be extended to larger numbers.